# Angularjs: ng-show expression within an ng-repeat - can I set a header element to be visible if any of the ng-repeat expressions evaluated to true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of users in the following format:

`[{Name:"Bob", Changed: false}, {Name:"Alice", Changed: true}]`

I want to display these users, with some marking that displays if the `Changed` property is true. I can do this easily with the below code.

```
<div ng-controller="UserController as uController">
  <div ng-repeat="user in uController.users" >
    {{user.Name}}
    <span ng-show="user.Changed"> - changed</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm looking to do is have a header that will display a marking if any of the `Changed` properties in the list of users is marked as true. I'm not sure how to do this. Is there a way to check if any of the `user.Changed` expressions have evaluated to true outside of the ng-repeat?

Sample code and plnkr below:

```
<div ng-controller="UserController as uController">
  <span>Users</span><span ng-show="???"> - one or more users have changed</span>
  <div ng-repeat="user in uController.users" >
    {{user.Name}}
    <span ng-show="user.Changed"> - changed</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/9tq9uMMhW2CuOA02w7tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ng-show= "(uController.users | filter:{ Changed: true}).length"
```

updated plunkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/TCS2d3srIGVCsXNjGPqV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I will provide an alternative solution (*manual check*). It uses `.reduce()` to do an *OR* operation on all of the `Changed` properties, but it can also be done in a for loop.

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('UserController', UserController);
  
function UserController() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.users = [{Name:"Bob",Changed: false},{Name:"Alice",Changed: true},{Name:"Jane",Changed: false},{Name:"John",Changed: false}];
  
  vm.check = function(){
    var r = (a,b)=>{return a | b.Changed};  // reducer
    return vm.users.reduce(r);              // evaluation
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
  <head><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script></head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="UserController as uController">
    
      <span>Users</span><span 
        ng-show="uController.check()"> - one or more users have changed</span>
        
      <div ng-repeat="user in uController.users">
        {{user.Name}}
        <span ng-show="user.Changed"> - changed</span>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```